# Probability of getting any single card.

Tags: probability

I am trying to calculate the probability of getting every single card from a maze of, lets say, 50 cards in 100 attempts.
The process is:  You get a card, note it down and return it to the maze. Then repeat 99 times more. At the end, what is the probability of having noted every card at least once?

I have calculated the probability of getting a single card, that is 1-(49/50)^100 that is more or less 87%.
But I am completely lost in finding the probability of getting every single card. I presume that should very a very low probability.

Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let the cards be indexed ($i=1,2,\dots,100$) and let $E_i$ denote the event that card $i$ will **not** be drawn.

Then you are searching for:$$1-\Pr(\bigcup_{i=1}^{100}E_i)$$

You can find that by means of the [inclusion/exclusion principle for probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability) combined with symmetry.